# github lists commit but file browser does not show it

Tags: git, github

I created a git clone of the master branch of my project in a different local directory to fix a bug because I was working on a development branch.

I fixed the bug and commited the change, and pushed it to github.

github shows the commit and the change.

[image]

But the main file browser of master shows no such commit:

[image]

Anyone help me understand what is going on? I verified that the commit has not propagated. I am not very expert at git but I did not think there would be much to this operation.

Comment: update, check which branch you're on

Comment: `git status` says I am on maser*

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your branch. I think you need to "push" all the changes to the master one and everything will be alright

Comment: `git status` shows I am on master*. I used `git push origin master` . What else should I be doing?

Comment: You should check to which branch it pushes

Comment: @sehe The screenshot shows he's on the master branch both in the diff view and the file view, but the file view isn't showing his changes.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister That's my point. What if `master` doesn't push to the `master` branch on origin...? It's not always matching named branches that are configured

Comment: @all I think I have screwed up the top level directory and added a parent dir from the clone. Argh. I am trying to figure it out now.

Comment: @sehe If I'm not mistaken, if that were the case then his diff view wouldn't show his change on the origin's master branch.

Comment: @metalaureate If you have the time, don't forget to add and accept your own answer if you figure it out - I haven't seen this problem before and I'm curious as to what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will be helpful, but the cause was my accidentally stupidly cloning the branch into a parent directory one level above where I should have.